# Randomly select 20 folders out of 50 in php, and then enumerate (thumbs) folder in each for thumbnails

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have written an image gallery for myself in php.

I am using 'foreach' to loop through gallery folders and display thumbnails on the main page.

I only want to return 20 galleries (well thumbnails) on the main page - but I want these 20 to be totally random.

So - I know I need to read my gallery folder names into an array first, and then randomize 20 folders from this array. How can I do that please?

Part of my code currently looks like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach(glob($galdir.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
     $thumbdir = ($dir . "/thumbs/");

    echo "<div class=\"picture titleleft\">\n";
    // echo "<div class=\"picture titleleft\" style=\"width:175px;\">\n";
    echo '<a href="showgal.php?gallery='. $dir . '">
    <img src="'.random_pic($thumbdir).'" alt="mypicturedlife gallery image" height="112px"></a>' . "\n";
    $galname = str_replace(array("galleries/"), "", $dir);
    $galleryname = str_replace(array("_"), " ", $galname);
    echo "$galleryname\n";
    echo "</div><!-- close picture titleleft -->\n";
    if (++$i == 20) break;
}
```

You'll see I have $i = 0 before the loop and then a break at the counf ot 20 within the loop.

This works fine - but of course only returns the first 20 galleries rather than random.

Thanks.

Comment: May be it would be better to get your folders into array variable first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, put all folders into an array :

```
$dirs = glob($galdir . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

then randomize the order of the elements in array with [shuffle()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) :

```
shuffle($dirs);
```

then select/extract first 20 of that array with [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) :

```
$dirs = array_slice($dirs, 0, 20);
```

then output this dirs/galleries onto your homepage like you did with your foreach :

```
foreach($dirs as $dir) {
    echo 
        '<div class="picture titleleft">' .
            '<a href="showgal.php?gallery=' . $dir . '">
                <img src="' . random_pic($dir . '/thumbs/') . '" alt="..." />' .
            '</a>' .
            str_replace(array("galleries/", "_"), array("", " "), $dir) .
        '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, save all galleries in an array.

```
$storage = glob($galdir . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Now, shuffle the array.

```
shuffle($storage);
```

You now have an array with all your galleries randomly sorted. Loop through them again.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) { //Only 20
    echo $storage[$i]; //Directory name. Add your HTML stuff here
}
```

Comment: Error happens if you have less than 20 folders. It can be easily fixed if you put `min()` in your `for` loop, like `for($i = 0; $i < min(20, count($storage)); $i++) {`

Answer (score 0):

this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php seems like the thing you need

Comment: I had already seen this page, but I couldn't work out how to make use of the function, as programming is not one of my primary skills!

Comment: This function returns random keys from given array, and then you must loop over this keys and select data from primary array via current key.